# Flutter: How to create a development APK that can be installed on the phone

Tags: android, flutter

I recently started working with flutter.  I have been making several test applications. They all work well on emulators.

But now I want to be able to use them on my cell phone.

I took the APK that is generated when I run the application in the emulator, indicated in this route:

[image]

But it always fails to install

[image]

So far, my applications are simple, Hello world, Add numbers, etc.

Any ideas?
How should I do it correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First: Open your Terminal/Shell/Command Line and open the directory of the Flutter App in there (cd PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE)

You probably want to create a profile-mode apk for testing. This build still helps debugging while having the speed of the --release version:

This creates a single APK which works on all devices (x64, arm64 and arm), it's probably pretty big:

```
flutter build apk --profile
```

If the people who install your App *know* which devices they have, you can use the split-per-abi command which creates three different APKs for all architectures (x64, arm64 and arm)

```
flutter build apk --profile --split-per-abi
```

If you want to have a release build, you can use what @Niteesh commented:

```
flutter build apk --release --split-per-abi
```

Release-builds can be uploaded to Google-Play (also the internal testing)

Read more: https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/build-modes

Comment: flutter build apk --profile installing fine but flutter build apk not installing Why?

Answer (score 2):

the apk that is generated when you run the app is the debug-apk, it contains lots of overheads which helps in flutter hot reload and hot restart. The size of debug apk version is also a lot.

use this command to generate release version of apk

```
flutter build apk --split-per-abi
```

After execution of the command, you get the path of the apk, something like this

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-armeabi-v7a-release.apk (7.0MB).
```

Then you can install that apk on your phone